# Connection with credentials to a non localhost mongodb using Play / scala / casbah /salat

Tags: mongodb, scala

Tried many ways and googled accross.
In my opinion it should work just by setting the configuration file like this:

```
mongodb.default.host="ahost"
mongodb.default.port=aport 
mongodb.default.db="adatabase"
mongodb.default.user="auser"
mongodb.default.password="apassword"
```

Can't find the documentation/sample code to authenticate successfully.

Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Are you using the latest play salat plugin? https://github.com/leon/play-salat

Comment: Not sure how to check that. I got a sample, the only one I found where it uses:  "com.novus" %% "salat" % "1.9.5"   Should I change that? to what version?

Comment: Just noticed there is a sample in your repo. I will try that...

Comment: Tried the sample app but it keeps connecting to local mongo in lieue of configured settingsin conf/application.conf

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: I've done a lot of changes and now it seems to work. I cannot pinpoint what was the root cause. But I am happy, thanks Ross.

Comment: No worries - I pleased its righted itself!